# Modifying Magento layout for specific pages or extensions without impacting other pages

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

New to Magento here, looking for advice in making sure I modify the correct files to limit the scope of changes and not run into any issues when updating. I installed the following extension for FAQ function:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/flagbit-faq.html

By default the front end FAQ page was displaying with 2 columns (1 left sidebar showing a product comparison block which was unnecessary on a FAQ page). I found the following file:

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/faq.xml
```

And changed:

```
<default>
<reference name="root">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
</default>
```

To:

```
<default>
<reference name="root">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
</default>
```

This had the desired result on the FAQ page, but also the undesired result of removing the compare box from the actual product list page. How would I best make the desired change to the FAQ page layout without impacting other pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their module's faq.xml shouldn't be setting that on the default node.

Inspect the page and look for the class on body. It might be something like cms-faq (should say something about faq). Convert the dash - to an underscore _ and use that value in place of default in faq.xml

```
<cms_faq>
    <reference name="root">
    ....
</cms_faq>
```

That should make sure the change to the setTemplate action only affects that page.

By setting default there, they are targeting all layout handles, which is really not what they should be doing in a module that just creates a new page.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. It was a free extension that otherwise works pretty well so I guess I can't be too upset about it. Is there a similar method for setting the contents of the columns? For example, if the left sidebar on the products page currently displays the compare box, could I make it also show the product filter?

Comment: The catalog navigation filter is a standalone block - a default declaration for that is in /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml -- approx. line 75 (block name is catalog.leftnav). If using the left column layout, you should be able to drop this under the node I referenced in my answer (cms_faq) and it should load. If it's for the right column, change the reference from left to right.